# wpf, Set Button "preserve" on a Style

Tags: wpf, button, styles, preserve

Given this for a single button:

```
<Button xml:space="preserve">  Send  </Button>
```

How does one set this for all buttons as a Style?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Style.Setters>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
  </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Comment: Seems like it would be more trouble to remember to add the whitespace to every instance than it would be to just add a margin of like 5,0 to the ContentPresenter in the button template so it adds a uniform consistent spacing everytime without extra effort wouldn't it?

Comment: @bhs67 - I don't think it can be set in default style? Why not to wrap all buttons in panel and set the value on panel and let child controls inherit it from there?

Comment: -1 down vote accept
 

There are quite a few buttons located on tabs, etc. They are different sizes. All heights are the same, have different widths, have different margins around the buttons.

The xml:space="preserve" works well ... but is cumbersome to add to every button.